# datagrid value to change a textbox to collapsed

Tags: xaml, datagrid, textbox

If a particular value in a selected row of datagrid is 1, I want to have a separate textbox collapsed.

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="TextBoxDetailsSafetyFactor" 
    Height="21" 
    Margin="0,0,2,15" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"  
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.487,0.507" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Width="96"
    >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SafetyFactor}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" ></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Code that works in the grid is below:

```
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SafetyFactor}" Value="1">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have used this code in another cell in the data grid to collapse.  I now want to collapse a text outside of the datagrid.

Comment: Why not set a similar style on the other element that you want to collapse?

Comment: I have used the same code as the code to collapse a field in the datagrid and it is show above.  It does not collapse the textbox.  I also want to have it collapse a label but that should be easy once I get it to collapse the textbox.

Comment: This is my code for the datagrid item that I was successfully able to collapse.